# MikTex 2.9 on Windows Server 2012, package management

Tags: miktex

I have installed MikTex 2.9 on Windows Server 2012. Users connect via Remote Desktop to the server and run LaTeX.

Currently, packages are installed in the users' home directory, i.e. new packages need to be installed for each user separately. For example in

```
C:\Users\sharmeela\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
```

How can I manage and install packages centrally in one location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install packages into one centalized location, you need to run *Update (Admin)* and *Package Manager (Admin)* from Start menu -> *MiKTeX 2.9* -> *Maintenance (Admin)*. Of course, only administrators are able to run these programs.

Comment: Works. @stu003 Thank you for this quick, helpful answer.